# INSERT INTO statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, data-warehouse

I'm trying to work with YEAR function on one column in the DB and then add the results to a different table in the DWH. 
What am I doing wrong?

```
INSERT INTO example_dwh1.dim_time (date_year)
SELECT YEAR(time_taken) 
FROM exampledb.photos;
```

When removing the INSERT INTO line, I get the results I want, but I'm not able to insert them into the dwh table.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What error do you get?  What is the definition of `dim_time`?

Comment: I'm not getting an error but the values don't appear in the dim_time table. what do you mean by definition? the field date_year is int(10)

Comment: he means what data type is dim_time? Is it also an int? a date? char?

Comment: So its simple you can not add `Y-m-d` date into an `int` datatype. Change the datatype to `date`

Comment: dim_time is the table name. date_year is a field name and his type is int(10). time_taken is a field name which is from type datetime

Comment: Sorry I thought he was talking about time_taken (even though he said dim_time), which is what I want to know. What is time_taken? a date?

Comment: If there are no error messages maybe you need to check you that committed your changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `select` works, but I don't see the data in the table after the `insert`:

```
INSERT INTO example_dwh1.dim_time (date_year)
    SELECT YEAR(time_taken) 
    FROM exampledb.photos;
```

There is rather broad.  Assuming you have no errors in the `insert`, you might have:

- You are incorrectly querying `dim_time`, so the data is there but your check is wrong.
- You are inserting into `dim_time` in one database but querying it in another.

Assuming you have errors but are missing them, here are some possibilities:

- The database does not exist.
- The table does not exist.
- The column is misnamed.
- Other columns are declared `NOT NULL`.
- Triggers defined on the table are preventing the `insert`.
- Unique constraints/indexes on the table are preventing the `insert`.

Your question does not provide enough information to be more specific.  However, it seems highly suspicious to be inserting a bunch of years -- which might include many duplicates -- into a dimension table.